# How to perform search upon clearing a noncollapsible SearchView?

Tags: android, searchview

[`SearchView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html) is a design standard, but has a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25758) where its [`OnCloseListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnCloseListener.html) (where I'd normally put the code to search without filtering) isn't called.
This is a problem if you only want to perform the search in [`onQueryTextSubmit`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html#onQueryTextSubmit(java.lang.String)) rather than [`onQueryTextChange`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html#onQueryTextChange(java.lang.String)).
The former isn't called when the query string is empty, and I don't want to search when the user erases it just to type something else - only when deliberately removing text filtering.

I am using [`setIconifiedByDefault(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setIconifiedByDefault(boolean)), as the design calls for an always-visible search bar - but even if this weren't the case, `onClose()` is only called when you 'iconify' the SearchView, upon the **second** click of the 'x' icon.

What is the best solution? Preferably without adding custom views over the SearchView, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: create your own view overlaying the SearchView, that performs the search when pressed. Only visible when the search string is empty but the last performed search used a nonempty string (no need otherwise).

```xml
<RelativeLayout>
    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/someValue"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/search"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/search"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/search"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/someIcon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```java
// assign to the overlaying ImageView
class OnClearClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Override
    public final void onClick(View v) {
        View clear = findViewById(R.id.clear);
        clear.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide, just did its job
        performSearch();
    }
}
// assign to SearchView
class OnFilterQueryTextListener implements OnQueryTextListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        boolean hide = newText != null && newText.length() > 0 ||
            !lastSearchUsedFilter(); // check value stored on successful response
        findViewById(R.id.clear).setVisibility(hide ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        findViewById(R.id.clear).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        performSearch();
        return false;
    }

});
```